# Selenium FirefoxOptions - how to set browser window to be maximised at start?

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver

I''m building some Jave/Junit Selenium tests to work with both Chrome and Firefox.

I can't find any info on how to start the Firefox browser window in a maximised state.   With Chrome I can use ChromeOptions, like:

anOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");

I can't find any way to make the same thing happen for Firefox and FirefoxOptions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

For `python` with `Firefox`you can use:

```
driver = Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've started your test and used `driver.get('http://your_url')` to navigate to your desired URL, you can maximize the browser window by using the following command:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Yep - I understand that's an option,  but I'd like to start the window in a maximised state.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do it through FirefoxOptions in a similar way to ChromeOptions? I'm open to correction on this but as far as I'm aware this is the only way to maximize the browser window in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've found is `anOptions.addArguments("--kiosk")`. This opens a maximized window but without the toolbar, address bar, etc.